# LINQ com Left Outer Join em ManyToMany

Tags: c#, linq, extension-method

Procurei muito sobre LINQ e Extension Methods, mas não encontrei uma solução para essa consulta que preciso fazer. O fato é que eu tenho o modelo abaixo (deixei apenas as entidades utilizadas) e preciso trazer a NotaFiscal, seu Status (da tabela NotaFiscal), e trazer se este status tem cadastro na tabela Permissão (aqui entra o LEFT OUTER JOIN):
[image: Models]

Estou tentando uma solução para uma *query* em LINQ ou *Extension Methods* que resulte na consulta SQL abaixo:

```
SELECT TOP 1000
[Extent1].[IdNotaFiscal] AS [IdNotaFiscal], 
[Extent1].[Numero] AS [Numero], 
[Extent1].[IdFornecedor] AS [IdFornecedor], 
[Extent1].[DataEmissao] AS [DataEmissao], 
[Extent1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus], 
[Extent1].[Valor] AS [Valor], 
[Extent2].[Status] AS [Status], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[IdPermissao] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
FROM   [dbo].[NotaFiscal] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[NotaFiscalStatus] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] = [Extent2].[IdNotaFiscalStatus]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Permissao] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] = [Extent2].[IdNotaFiscalStatus]
--Até aqui já consegui usando o Extension Methods, conforme próximo trecho de código
--A linha abaixo que preciso adicionar, a variável já está com valor atribuído
AND [Extent3].[IdAcessoTipo] = @IdAcessoTipo
```

Com o código abaixo cheguei o mais próximo do esperado, mas ainda preciso filtrar pelo `idAcessoTipo`:

```
            var notasfiscais = (from s in db.NotaFiscal select s)
                                   .Include(n => n.NotaFiscalStatus) 
                                   .Include(p => p.NotaFiscalStatus.Permissao);
```

Que resultou na *query* abaixo, a qual faz uma consulta duplicada (seria melhor se não fizesse):

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Sequencia] AS [Sequencia], 
[Project1].[IdNotaFiscal] AS [IdNotaFiscal], 
[Project1].[Numero] AS [Numero], 
[Project1].[IdFornecedor] AS [IdFornecedor], 
[Project1].[DataEmissao] AS [DataEmissao], 
[Project1].[Parcelas] AS [Parcelas], 
[Project1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus], 
[Project1].[Valor] AS [Valor], 
[Project1].[DataHoraCadastro] AS [DataHoraCadastro], 
[Project1].[DataHoraAlteracao] AS [DataHoraAlteracao], 
[Project1].[IdUsuarioAlteracao] AS [IdUsuarioAlteracao], 
[Project1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus1] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus1], 
[Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Project1].[BotaoIncremento] AS [BotaoIncremento], 
[Project1].[FluxoAprovacao] AS [FluxoAprovacao], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[IdPermissao] AS [IdPermissao], 
[Project1].[IdAcessoTipo] AS [IdAcessoTipo], 
[Project1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus2] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[IdNotaFiscal] AS [IdNotaFiscal], 
    [Extent1].[Numero] AS [Numero], 
    [Extent1].[IdFornecedor] AS [IdFornecedor], 
    [Extent1].[DataEmissao] AS [DataEmissao], 
    [Extent1].[Parcelas] AS [Parcelas], 
    [Extent1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus], 
    [Extent1].[Valor] AS [Valor], 
    [Extent1].[DataHoraCadastro] AS [DataHoraCadastro], 
    [Extent1].[DataHoraAlteracao] AS [DataHoraAlteracao], 
    [Extent1].[IdUsuarioAlteracao] AS [IdUsuarioAlteracao], 
    [Extent2].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus1], 
    [Extent2].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent2].[Sequencia] AS [Sequencia], 
    [Extent2].[BotaoIncremento] AS [BotaoIncremento], 
    [Extent2].[FluxoAprovacao] AS [FluxoAprovacao], 
    [Extent3].[IdPermissao] AS [IdPermissao], 
    [Extent3].[IdAcessoTipo] AS [IdAcessoTipo], 
    [Extent3].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] AS [IdNotaFiscalStatus2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[IdPermissao] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   [dbo].[NotaFiscal] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[NotaFiscalStatus] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] = [Extent2].[IdNotaFiscalStatus]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Permissao] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[IdNotaFiscalStatus] = [Extent1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[IdNotaFiscal] ASC, [Project1].[IdNotaFiscalStatus1] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Tentei usar *GroupJoin* e *Where* e combinações diversas com os mesmos, mas sem sucesso. Seguem as classes envolvidas:

NotaFiscal.cs:

```
public partial class NotaFiscal
{
    public NotaFiscal()
    {
        this.Parcela = new HashSet<Parcela>();
    }

    public long IdNotaFiscal { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public long IdFornecedor { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Parcelas { get; set; }
    public long IdNotaFiscalStatus { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataHoraCadastro { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DataHoraAlteracao { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> IdUsuarioAlteracao { get; set; }

    public virtual ACESSO ACESSO { get; set; }
    public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Parcela> Parcela { get; set; }
    public virtual NotaFiscalStatus NotaFiscalStatus { get; set; }
}
```

NotaFiscalStatus.cs:

```
public partial class NotaFiscalStatus
{
    public NotaFiscalStatus()
    {
        this.Permissao = new HashSet<Permissao>();
    }

    public long IdNotaFiscalStatus { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int Sequencia { get; set; }
    public string BotaoIncremento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> FluxoAprovacao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permissao> Permissao { get; set; }
}
```

Permissao.cs:

```
public partial class Permissao
{
    public long IdPermissao { get; set; }
    public long IdAcessoTipo { get; set; }
    public long IdNotaFiscalStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual AcessoTipo AcessoTipo { get; set; }
    public virtual NotaFiscalStatus NotaFiscalStatus { get; set; }
}
```

AcessoTipo.cs:

```
public partial class AcessoTipo
{
    public AcessoTipo()
    {
        this.ACESSO = new HashSet<ACESSO>();
        this.Permissao = new HashSet<Permissao>();
    }

    public long IdAcessoTipo { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ACESSO> ACESSO { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permissao> Permissao { get; set; }
}
```

Encontrei alguns casos semelhantes, mas a implementação dos mesmos não causaram o resultado esperado.

**Edit:**

O mais próximo que cheguei foi com LINQ, com o código abaixo, mas a cláusula *Where* precisa estar dentro do último join para trazer as tuplas nulas da tabela permissão:

```
var notasfiscais3 = from s in db.NotaFiscal
                            join n in db.NotaFiscalStatus on s.IdNotaFiscalStatus equals n.IdNotaFiscalStatus
                            join p in db.Permissao on n.IdNotaFiscalStatus equals p.IdNotaFiscalStatus
                            where p.IdAcessoTipo == idAcessoTipo
                            let y = new { n, s, Permissao = p == null ? 0 : 1 }
                            select y;
```

E tentando fazer a comparação com o código abaixo é apresentado o erro "O tipo de uma das expressões na cláusula join está incorreto. Inferência de tipos falhou na chamada para "Join".":

```
var notasfiscais4 = from s in db.NotaFiscal
                            join n in db.NotaFiscalStatus on s.IdNotaFiscalStatus equals n.IdNotaFiscalStatus
                            join p in db.Permissao on new {n.IdNotaFiscalStatus, idAcessoTipo}
                            equals new {p.IdNotaFiscalStatus, p.IdAcessoTipo}
                            let y = new { n, s, Permissao = p == null ? 0 : 1 }
                            select y;
```

Mesmo tentando fazer *cast* para o tipo `long` de várias formas em `idAcessoTipo`.

**Edit2:**
Consegui criar a query, mas retorna um `IQuerable` de um tipo anônimo, causando conflito com o tipo NotaFiscal. Será que tem outra forma de fazer para retornar do mesmo tipo com campos a mais?
Segue o código:

```
var notasfiscais = (from s in db.NotaFiscal select s);
notasfiscais = notasfiscais.Include(n => n.NotaFiscalStatus);
///
// Aqui existe alguns filtros com método Where
///
var notasfiscaisresultado = notasfiscais.Include(p => p.NotaFiscalStatus.Permissao)
            .GroupJoin(db.Permissao, n => n.IdNotaFiscalStatus, p => p.IdNotaFiscalStatus,
            (n, p) => new { NotaF = n, Permissao = p });
// Acima tive que criar outra variável para aceitar o novo tipo anônimo
```

Comment: se tem que fazer isso com `join` para dar certo

Comment: Eu fiz com dois joins e ele "apaga" o primeiro (from n in db.NotaFiscal                                  join s in db.NotaFiscalStatus on n.IdNotaFiscalStatus equals s.IdNotaFiscalStatus                                 join m in db.Permissao on s.IdNotaFiscalStatus equals m.IdNotaFiscalStatus                                 where m.IdAcessoTipo == idAcessoTipo select n)